# The multiple select checkboxes of Custom UITableviewcell is not selecting

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, checkbox

I use below code for sending my `UITableViewCell` to editing mode:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 3;
}
```

when I enable editing mode the checkboxes of editing mode appears in my cells but when I click on the cells only the background changes, the checkbox not selecting or deselecting.

Does anyone have any idea about what is wrong??

I set the `selectionStyle` of the cells like below:

```
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleGray];
```

now, checkboxes is checking but when the cell is more higher, a line is adding to center of cell too!!

Comment: Why are you returning `3` for the editing style? Use one of the proper `UITableViewCellEditingStyle` enum values.